# JQuery's .on() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting things up very simply and i just can't wrap my brain why this won't work. I know this is correct, yet it doesn't work.

`.navigate-button` is being ajax'd into `.overlay-content` so `.overlay-content` isn't in the dom on page load, hence using `.on`

When i click the link it just takes me to the page as normal. I know that the even tisn't being bound to `.navigate-button`

Mark Up:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content--bg">
        <div class="overlay-content">

    <a class="navigate-button left" href="/question.php?id=<?php echo $json->id-1;$json->id+1; ?>">
        <
    </a>
    <a class="navigate-button right" href="/question.php?id=<?php echo $json->id+1; ?>">
        >
    </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS: if i run this code in console it works as expected

```
$('#overlay').on('click','.navigate-button', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    id = id.split('=');
    console.info(id[1]);
    callPage(id[1]);
    return false;
});

function callPage (id) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/question.php?id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            $('.overlay-content').html(data);
            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('overlay'));
            $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: o ye, forgot to mention there were no js errors. I want to take everything after =, which is what the 1 is for

Comment: You're actually taking everything *before* `=` in your example... see: http://jsfiddle.net/sHhHA/

Comment: Why do you parse your id when you are calling exactly what is written in href?

Comment: argh cool :), but thats not really the problem. I hadn't got to tested it yet as it won't run.

Comment: @OptimusCrime this function is being used on many places that don't have a href. This is just as a fall back to get people to the page without js

Comment: What is HTTP response to this AJAX request? Can you post the head and body?

Comment: Your JS code seems ok. Maybe it's the invalid HTML? you can't have `<` and `>`, you should use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: @thisgeek there is no http response as i'm not getting ajax, it is forwarding me to the page. My bad for not making this clearer

Comment: good point @bfavaretto but no luck

Comment: So your going to a new page, and your wondering why the javascript you had on the previous page stopped working ?

Comment: Did you wrap that javascript in a DOM ready function by the way ?

Comment: @adeneo as you can see in the markup the targeted selector is a href, but return false will stop the normal functionality and stop the a from going to the link.

Comment: If it's not preventing the default action of the anchor, it's not working at all, and your either not hitting the target, i.e. wrong selector, or you forgot to wrap it in document.ready ?

Comment: @adeneo my js is at the bottom of the page, so the dom will be ready by the time it finds this function. Also, just for safer knowledge, i have .on working on another element calling `callPage` and its working perfectly.

Comment: Try commenting out the FB.XFBML.parse function and see it it works, as that replaces some elements, but I'm not sure if it replaces the element it's called on, but I would think so, and if that element is replaced your handler is useless, and the answer below would be somewhat correct, and you did of course try the answer below?

Comment: No luck with commenting out fb. its crazyiness... as in, why its not working.

Comment: And you did include jQuery ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20082/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-adeneo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this in chat. Jamie's problem was that the click event on the `.navigate-button` div wasn't bubbling up to the `#overlay` div because it was being caught and handled in between by a handler that called `.stopPropagation` on it. The solution was to remove that intermediate handler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(document).on('click', '.navigate-button', function() {
    YOUR FUNCTION
});
```

Comment: this will not help as i'm targeting my elements parent as i should be.

Comment: Try switching `(document)` with `('body')`. That should work.